# Convert Collection to sResultSet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, objectinputstream

I'm working on a J2EE application.

[image: Here the structure of my Application]

I m trying to send a Collection of my object to my Applet 'AppletSaisie'.

Actually, I'm using a basic SQL request  : ServletRequete.java :

```
try
    {
        //Exécution de la requête
        BD=ds.getConnection();
        Statement s = BD.createStatement();
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select * from hockey");
        //Transformation du ResultSet en sResultSet
        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData columnNames = r.getMetaData();
        SResultSet.SerializedResultSet sResultSet = new SResultSet.SerializedResultSet();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnNames.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            sResultSet.addColumn(columnNames.getColumnName(i), i);
        }
    while (r.next()) {
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnNames.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        sResultSet.addColumnData(column, r.getObject(column));
    }
   }
    r.close();
    s.close();
    BD.close();
    s = null;
    r = null;
    return sResultSet;
    }
    catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erreur d'exécution de la requête SQL \n"+ex);
        return null;
    }
```

My Applet : AppletSaisie.java :

```
try
            {
            // Connexion à la servlet
            URL url=new URL("http://localhost:8080/ProjetHockeyWeb/ServletRequete");
            URLConnection connexion=url.openConnection();
            connexion.setDoOutput(true);
            // Récupération du flux de sortie
        /*  ObjectOutputStream fluxsortie = new
            ObjectOutputStream(connexion.getOutputStream());
            // Envoi du nom à rechercher
            fluxsortie.writeObject(nom);
            */
            // Récupération du flux d’entrée
            ObjectInputStream fluxentree = new
            ObjectInputStream(connexion.getInputStream());
            // Récupération du résultat de la requête
            SerializedResultSet donnees=(SerializedResultSet) fluxentree.readObject();
            // affichage du résultat
            donnees.first();
            Vector contenu=new Vector();
            contenu.clear();
            listeResultat.setListData(contenu);
            for (int i=0; i<donnees.recordCount();i++)
            {
            res=donnees.getString("nom")+" "+donnees.getString("prenom");
            contenu.addElement(res);
            donnees.next();
            }

            listeResultat.setListData(contenu);
            }
            catch (Exception sql)
            {
            System.out.println("erreur "+sql);
            }
```

This actually works, but now i'm using EJB. I want to use this wich gives me a Collection of my Object :

```
GardienManagerRemote gardienManagerRemote = EjbLocator.getLocator().getGardienManager();
Collection<Gardien> = gardienManagerRemote.listerGardien());
```

How can I pass my collection to my applet using ObjectInputStream